# Java ResourceBundles umlauts messed up

Tags: java, character-encoding, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have an issue with german "umlauts" in properties files. Now i totally get that i have to escape characters that are out of ISO-8859-1 range and i used native-to-ascii conversion in the past for this.

But why are umlauts like "ü" messed up too? They ARE part of ISO-8859-1 and if read the documentation right ResourceBundles in Java ARE read using ISO-8859-1. Also i use that encoding for my properties files.
Can someone enlighten me why this is happening?

**Example Code:**

create a .properties containing the following message (make sure it is saved as ISO-8859-1)

```
testMessage=ä ü ö Ä Ü Ö this message is used to test ResourceBundle - loading!
```

create a testclass with the following testmethod:

```
@Test
public void testEncoding() {
    String mess = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n.messages").getString("testMessage");
    Assert.assertEquals("ä ü ö Ä Ü Ö this message is used to test ResourceBundle - loading!", mess);
}
```

Now in my case the result is:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :ä ü ö Ä Ü Ö this message is used to test ResourceBundle - loading!
Actual   :ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ ï¿½ this message is used to test ResourceBundle - loading!
```

***EDIT**: 
It seems like this is a problem with my IntelliJ. If i execute the unit test and check target/i18n/messages.properties than the properties are already messed up there. I double checked the encoding of the source-file (in notepad) and also verified that my IDE interprets it as ISO-8859-1. Still no clue :(

Comment: this tests runs just fine for me

Comment: Are you sure you saved the properties file in ISO-8859-1, because it looks like it is saved in UTF-8.

Comment: Correction, all your characters seems to be encoded as 0xEFBFBD, which is the character replacement symbol in UTF-8.

Comment: I edited my answer above. This seems to be related to my IDE, if i execute the test with Maven it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ResourceBundle`  loads contents in `ISO-8859-1` format when converted to `String`s. One solution (bad-hack?) I use in my project is the following:

I get the `String` value, get the bytes of it and create a `new String` with `UTF-8` encoding. This solves my issues with umlauts.

```
new String(ResourceBundle.getBundle("your.folder").getString("testMessage").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: If you need to do this, then you actually saved the file as UTF-8, not ISO-8859-1; not to mention that you will lose any characters outside of ISO-8859-1 that were in the properties file with a proper unicode escape.

Comment: Of course I save the file as UTF-8 because I want to save it like that. That's why it is a problem that `ResourceBundle` loads strings as ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8. Proper unicode escape is out of question because I don't want to write every time `\u00FC` instead of `ü` every time I edit my properties.

Comment: I hope you know that not all bytes are valid ISO-8859-1, so some byte combinations in UTF-8 simply can't be rendered that way. If you really want to use UTF-8, you might want to consider using the XML format instead.

Comment: I know this. Fortunately we don't use that broad spectrum of UTF-8. However thanks for the idea.

Comment: Another option would be to use [`native2ascii`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html) as part of your build process

Answer (score 1):

Your test runs fine for me using Eclipse and ISO-8859-1 encoded properties file. But note that the two strings you provided differ:

```
ä ü ö Ä Ü Ö this message is used to test ResourceBundle - loading
```

vs

```
ä ü ö Ä Ü Ö this message is used to test resource Bundle-loading
```

So maybe the test is failing because of this, and the output is just messed up because the encoding og your console/logfile is not correct?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed my example above, still the same problem though. I already thought about the console messing things up and tested it by printing out special characters. That doesn't seem to be the problem. It's interesting that this is working for you though. Are you using an eclipse plugin that does native-to-ascii conversion maybe?